# adding html with jquery

Tags: jquery

is there a neat way to add html with jQuery instead of

```
$("#elm").html($("#elm").html() + "some text");
```

It'd be great to just do `$("#elm").html(+= "some text")` or something similar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#elm').append('some text');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append for more information on using append

Comment: So doing this would just append a text node?

Comment: if you do .append('<span>some text</span>') you'll get it in a span ;)